# Does deleting a subset of an infinite set that has strictly smaller cardinality leave the cardinality of the infinite set unchanged?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Is it a theorem of [ZFC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory) that if

1. $X \subseteq Y$,
2. $|X| < |Y|$,
3. $Y$ is infinite,

then

- $|Y \setminus X|=|Y|$?

Comment: I do like your questions, and they do give me good opportunities not to shut up, and ramble on and on about set theory. But sometimes I find your motivation a bit strange, if you want to truly understand a lot of these things then you'll have to sit down and try to solve the problems yourself. This is a prime example of something that really just requires writing down the basics of cardinal additions in $\sf ZFC$ to get the answer. There's nothing wrong in asking this here, but it may help you a lot more to try and tackle this sort of problem for a week before posting it here.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, you're absolutely correct. This website is making me intellectually lazy, and I really would be better off trying to puzzle out more things for myself. Anyway, thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 7):

Yes it is, it follows from $\kappa + \lambda = \max(\kappa, \lambda)$ if at least one of the cardinals in question is infinite.

So suppose $|Y \setminus X| < |Y|$, than as $Y$ is infinte either $X$ or $|Y \setminus X|$ is infinite, so 
$$ |Y| = |Y \setminus X| + |X|  = \max(|X|, |Y \setminus X|) < |Y| $$
contradiction. Hence $|Y \setminus X| = |Y|$.